# How to change Google sign-in to display profile information instead of console.log

Tags: javascript, google-signin, console.log

I have implemented Google sign-in on my website using the tutorial given by Google. However, instead of storing the profile information in console.log, I want to display it on my webpage. This is the code that I currently have:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
<script>
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId());
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
    };
</script>
```

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you haven't done so, you need to start by [Creating a Google API Console project and client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project).

If you already did this, continue with embedding the necessary code into your HTML. And to do that first you have to give reference to **Google Platform** by adding this line between your `<head>` and `</head>` tags.

```
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

Then insert the code **below** between your `<body>` and `</body>` tags.

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

And now it is time to call the function, and assign User's Data to HTML. Add these lines inside `<script></script>` tags inside your `<body>`

> NOTE: You may call it from another file, but i am not going to mention it here.

```
  <script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
   var data = '';
     data += '<ul>';
     data += '<li><img src="' + profile.getImageUrl() + '"/></li>';
     data += '<li>ID: ' + profile.getId() + '</li>';
     data += '<li>Full Name: ' + profile.getName() + '</li>';
     data += '<li>Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName() + '</li>';
     data += '<li>Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName() + '</li>';
     data += '<li>Email: ' + profile.getEmail() + '</li>';
     data += '</ul>';
  document.getElementsByClassName("aClassOfYourOwn")[0].innerHTML =data;
};
</script>
```

> NOTE 2: This is only one way of handling this, as you may assign new variables, and call them anywhere you like, but this is only for starter.

Now, it is time to create a new div. So that you can use what you get from Google. So in order to do this add this line inside your `<body>` tag.

```
<div class="aClassOfYourOwn"></div>
```

Maybe right after

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

It is up to you.
Finally if you want to add signout option, add this line inside your `<body>` tag.

```
<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
```

And of course, as you may have seen, we did not declare a function called `signOut()`. So lets go and declare it.

```
<script>
function signOut() {
  var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
  auth2.signOut().then(function () {
    console.log('User signed out.');
    var data = 'There is no user signed in';
    document.getElementsByClassName("g-signin3")[0].innerHTML =data;
  });
}
</script>
```

This is just for demo. Of course showing **User Data** back to the user is meaningless. But what you can do with it is limitless.
For example, you can get the IDs and direct the users to their respective pages.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've just tried implementing this solution now and it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: It's giving the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: Do you have Jquery in your HTML? If not, you must download it, or give reference like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">`

If you already have it, then this error may be triggered by wrong positioning of script references.

Comment: Is there a way to do it using JavaScript?

Comment: I have tried to implement this by changing the last line of code but it still isn't working

Comment: Sorry to hear that, have you checked your console?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("newClass")[0].innerHTML =data;` should work. The process is simple. I just tried, and it is working properly. But don't forget to add an index to the class. Are you sure you created a Google API Console project and client ID?

Comment: By the way, DO NOT use the same class `g-signin2`. But use a new instead. I edited my code above.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is now giving this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined at onSignIn" after I changed the final line of code to "document.getElementsByClassName("yourNewClass")[0].innerHTML =data;"

Comment: That is because you haven't created a new div with the class `yourNewClass`. [Here](http://mizansenmedya.com/test.php) is a working version that i just made. But It is hard to continue with commenting here. I'm going to edit my answer, and show you how i did it.